# filled faces have weird shadows

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces

when I want to fill 4 selected vertices to get a face to connect 2 different objects, the face gets weird shadows and I also can't sculpt the face. How can I remove these shadows and create a normal face ? :
[image]

video : file:///C:/Users/WIN10/Videos/Movavi%20Screen%20Recorder/ScreenRecorderProject130.mp4

Comment: May be wrong normal direction on the new face. Turn on backface culling to check it.

Comment: thanks, this was the problem !

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)